# IllegalArgumentException when running Maven build on Customer Provided Executor

Tags: maven, jenkins, cloudbees

I connected my computer to my CloudBees Jenkins using the customer [provided executors](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Customer+Provided+Slaves) feature. When I try to run a maven build, I get this error:

```
FATAL: Null value not allowed as an environment variable: M2_HOME
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null value not allowed as an environment variable: M2_HOME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Mavens provided by default on DEV@cloud use the Pre-Installed Maven versions available on DEV@cloud build machines. Since you are providing your own executors, you must tell Jenkins where to find Maven or how to install it. You can do this by editing your Maven Installations under $JENKINS_URL/configure.

You can click the "Install Automatically" option on an existing Maven installation, or you can add a new Maven installation for your customer provided executors.

If you want to make use of existing maven installation, just add another maven installation and don't check "Install automatically" or "Use pre-installed versions on DEV@cloud".